# Yii urser-friendly url using urlManager

Tags: yii

I am getting an HTTP 404 error when I try to rewrite my URL's in Yii with urlManager.

Here are two config formats I've tried in my main.php config file, one like `'pattern1'=>'route1'` and the other in the new format `array('route1', 'pattern'=>'pattern1')`:

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
                'messageBulk'=>'message/apiBulk'
            ),
        ),

'urlManager' => array(
                'urlFormat' => 'path',
                'rules' => array(
                    array('message/apiBulk', 'pattern'=>'messageBulk')
                ),
            ),
```

Comment: What's the debug panel show?  What URL are you trying to access with your rules? Does your http://yourwebsite.com/index.php/message/apiBulk work?

Comment: yes, yourwebsite.com/index.php/message/apiBulk works thank you! I was unaware that you needed to put index.php in front. How do I go about removing that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was writing the URL wrong, missing "index.php". Answer was in @ernie's comment.

> What's the debug panel show? What URL are you trying to access with your rules? Does your yourwebsite.com/index.php/message/apiBulk work?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of urls are you looking to generate? Cos I'm a bit confused with the configurations you've got up there. At any rate, this is a template I use for my projects:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
             // REST patterns
            array('api/list', 'pattern'=>'api/v1/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('api/view', 'pattern'=>'api/v1/<model:\w+>/check', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('api/view', 'pattern'=>'api/v1/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
            array('api/create', 'pattern'=>'api/v1/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'POST'),

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        ),
        //'showScriptName'=>false,
    ),
```

I hope it helps you out.